# elasticsearch dsl python unpack q queries

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py, q-query

How can I dynamically create a combined Q query in elasticsearch dsl python?
I have gone through [docs](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#filters) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564303/how-do-i-create-an-or-filter-using-elasticsearch-dsl-py). I constructed a q_query dictionary with all required info.

```
ipdb> q_queries
{'queries': [{'status': 'PASS'}, {'status': 'FAIL'}, {'status': 'ABSE'}, {'status': 'WITH'}], 'operation': 'or'}
```

I want to perform the following q_query

```
qq=Q("match", status='PASS') | Q("match", status="FAIL") | Q("match", status="ABSE") | Q("match", status="WITH")
```

for a list of dict following works out

```
ipdb> [Q('match', **z) for z in q_queries['queries']]
[Match(status='PASS'), Match(status='FAIL'), Match(status='ABSE'), Match(status='WITH')]
```

But How to combine multiple Qs with an or operator or an and operator? Also what is the corresponding `elasticsearch raw query` for the above? I tried following since I have to filter based on test_id.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":     [
        { "match": { "test_id": "7" }},
        {
          "range": {
            "created": {
              "gte": "2016-01-01",
              "lte": "2016-01-31"
            }
          }
        }
        ],
      "should": [
                  { "match": { "status": "PASS"}},
                  { "match": { "status": "FAIL"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But results are not as expected I same query without `should filter` and the results obtained were the same. So should filters were not executed by elasticsearch in my case.
Any help is much appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After exploring elasticsearch dsl python for some more time, [this piece of documentation](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#query-combination) helped me to solve above issue. Below posted is the function that I wrote to resolve this issue.

```
def create_q_queries(self, q_queries, search_query):
    """
    create q queries and chain if multiple q queries.
    :param q_queries: Q queries with operation and query params as a dict.
    :param search_query: Search() object.
    :return: search_query updated with q queries.
    """
    if q_queries:
        logical_operator_mappings = {'or': 'should', 'and': 'must'}
        for query in q_queries:
            queries = [Q('match', **query) for query in query['queries']]
            search_query = search_query.query(Q('bool', **{
                logical_operator_mappings.get(query.get('operation')): queries
            }))
    return search_query
```

I changed format of q_queries to perform chaining based on multiple operators like `and`, `or` etc.

```
q_queries = [
              {
                "operation": "or",
                "queries":
                  [
                    {"status": "PASS"}, {"status": "FAIL"}, {"status": "ABSE"}, {"status": "WITH"}
                  ]
                }

             ]
```